# Ajax post dictionary with comma separated value

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I have a dictionary as follow

```
var selectedKeys = {
        "bu": bu_keys,
        "be": be_keys,
    }
```

The `bu_keys , be_keys` each has a string separated with comma.
Example:
possible value for bu_keys is: "12354,abccsd,dsdfdlk,d35487" 
when i send this to my controller i got only the first part of the string which is 12354

```
$.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("Download", "Reports")",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: { allKeys: selectedKeys },
        success:  function (selectedKeys) {
            //do nothing
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert("Error: Please refresh the page and try again!" + status + " " + error + " " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }
    });
public FileResult DownLoad(Dictionary<string, string> allKeys)
    {
      // code here

    }

    public FileResult DownLoad2(Dictionary<string, string[]> allKeys)
    {
        // code here
    }
```

How can i get all the string not only the first part of the string, i tried both actions Download and DownLoad2, with no success

Comment: `data: { allKeys: selectedKeys }` should be : `data: selectedKeys `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the data via json type . Code sample below is for your reference :

```
var selectedKeys = {
    "bu": "12354,abccsd,dsdfdlk,d35487",
    "be": "12354,abccsd,dsdfdlk,d35487",
    }

$.ajax({
    url: '/Download/Reports',
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(selectedKeys),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success:  function (selectedKeys) {
        //do nothing
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert("Error: Please refresh the page and try again!" + status + " " + error + " " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
    }
});
```

Controller :

```
public IActionResult Reports([FromBody]MyModel myModel)
{
    ....
    return Json("OK");
}

public class MyModel { 
    public string bu { get; set; }
    public string be { get; set; }
}
```